# Setting rectangle at right angles to axes

Tags: vertices, transforms, transform-orientation

I have a rectangle that is rotated off square relative to the XZ plane:

[image]

How do I reorient the rectangle to be square with the XZ plane?

Answer (score 3):

Select two edges on the right and the left and all the side walls that should match them.   Then choose an axes that goes through them that will help them to line up, like this: press S, X and 0.  They should line up.
Then select two edges on the top and bottom and walls that should be parallel with them.  Press S, Z and 0 and they will line up.
Works in some cases, in others you have to rebuild.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a slight addition, in order for the above method to work, you'll have to change the "Transform Pivot Point" option on top, from the default, Median Point, to Individual Origins